# Saving processing results in a file using QGIS modeler?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler, save

From a model, I would like to save processing results in a file. In my model I have some `Extract by location` algorithms (with two vector inputs) producing reasonable results but only as temporary layers, which I have to `Save as...` manually, which for a pile of analyses is bothering and time consuming.

Best, I would like to pass a path to my model, where my results are saved as shapefiles (in a first step).

This is the model. Note that the output vector (file) cannot connect to any of the processing results:

[image]

As can be seen in the screenshots a), we are able to pass a name for a final result, but not a file, even in the `Save selected features` algorithm b).

a)
[image]

b)
[image]

I have a vague idea how to achieve this with a python script, but can this be done with a combination of existing tools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to pass a path in your model to save your shapefiles into instead of doing it manually, a **custom script** is probably the way to go. You can write a script to run the **Extract by location** tool and define the path of the output. Something like this perhaps:

```
##Extract_by_location=name
##Layer=vector
##Additional_layer=vector

layer = processing.getObject(Layer)
output_path = "C:/Users/You/Desktop/" + layer.name() + ".shp"

processing.runalg("qgis:extractbylocation", Layer, Additional_layer, u'contains', 0.00, output_path)
```

Replace the **Extract by location** tools in your model with this script and it will save the results to a shapefile in the path you specified.

Answer (score 5):

QGIS modeler treats any tool as intermediate which does not save any output, unless otherwise stated.

To force the model to export a result, you have to input a layer output name in the Tool row.

[image]

If I want to export the above result as a layer, I input a value  in the output as so:
[image]

What this does is add a dialoge box whenyou run the tool that you can set the output file:

[image]

The model itself shows the types of data with colors: purple for inputs, cyan for outputs

Comment: This is true indeed, but it is the same effort as leaving the output vectors as temporary files and then doing `rightclick > Save As...` for each of them.